# JAAS and jdbcRealm with desktop application

Tags: java, security, glassfish, ejb, jaas

I've successfully used JAAS with a JDBC realm for authenticationg users on a web application. However, I have a desktop application that also needs to inquire for a user and password on launch, and also call some protected EJBs. I'm not sure how to do that, the tutorials in the Oracle documentation don't really expose that much on how should I configure Glassfish, or the aplication itself (where to set up the realm), how to annotate the beans (luckily I have seperate beans for the desktop). Or, for example, where should I configure the mappings for the desktop? Is there a tutorial or a document I'm missing on that subject?

Is there a similar way of doing that like in a web application, with XML configuration and annotations or such?

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution. I had to follow this tutorial, only.

http://blog.enterpriselab.ch/tdmarti/2010/12/30/jaas-configuration-in-an-enterprise-application/

It's a very similar setup as in the web application, but with a few changes. I had to add glasfish-application.xhl on in the enterprise application project. I also forgot to add the application client module in the Java EE project, so it was basically standalone.

Comment: The above link is broken. I've got similar problems with yours now, and hardly find any similar tutorials or docs about how to setup the jdbcrealm and JAAS to work in the desktop application. Do you have any direction of how to do this? What configuration files are needed?

Comment: @HabibRosyad I actually dug out the old project and looked through it. I can't find a sign of these configurations, I'm actually no sure that we ended up using it after all.

Comment: No worries. I ended up defining `@RolesAllowed` in the EJBs by following this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/secure-ejb.html) and define my custom JDBCRealm in the glasfish-application.xml instead of using the default file realm. Although I still have no idea how to achieve the JAAS flexibility as in the web app, I think this will do for now.